# Bootstrap row on top of another

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am expanding my frontend css skills a little and I am trying to achieve the following: two bootstrap rows that overlap, but keep their **responsive grid-like** behaviour. Totally new to me, no idea how to tackle this..

So basically I want to have two columns side by side (that keep repeating as far as the content goes) and then another row with another column that overlaps them. This is needed to have the middle column (in row 2 on the image) be visable over all the red columns.

How would I do this? I want to keep the grid functionalities ofcourse.

[image: See the grid structure here]

This is a **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dmjwyvx/)** I made to give a better understanding. The grid does not really behave like it should imo. Also I don't think `position: absolute` is good for responsive websites.

I hope my question is clear enough! Thanks in advance

Comment: Made a simple jsfiddle.. (see original post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolute position will work, but make sure it's full height and the container is `position: relative;`

```
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  height:100%;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/B5mmRpPQ3y

Comment: Looks so simple when you do it! Thanks this was what I was looking for, does not break the grid!